# Slice assignment with empty list - why?

Tags: python, slice

i have a question. I afraid that it can be obvious to you, but i don't quite understand this at this moment.

I just readed about slice assignment and how assignment of empty list works like delete item, f.e.:

```
>> L=['a','b','c','d']
>> L[2:3] = []
>> L
['a', 'b', 'd']
```

But here is my question - won't it be more logical to more expect this output?

```
['a', 'b', [], 'd']
```

I know that output above will be true if my code will look like this:

```
>> L=['a','b','c','d']
>> L[2:3] = [[]]
>> L
```

but why it's constructed this way and not like f.e.:

```
>> L=['a','b','c','d']
>> L[2:3] = None
>> L
```

It look over-complicated to me, cause i expect that when i do slice assignment i don't expect in this situation that it will change the length of my list or maybe i want just to remove the slice and initiate an empty list at the same time.

EDIT: I don't know if i was clear enough - **i did't understand why - when doing slice assignment - python interpreter delete an item in list instead of change this item for empty list.**

Comment: Slicing DOES change the length of the list in this case -- it is removing data from the list. If you don't want the length of your list to change, put a value like an empty string in there: L[2:3] = ''. Then the list will be ['a', 'b', '', 'd']

Comment: Why would inserting an empty list make any sense? Why not an empty tuple, or an empty dict, or None? Slice assignment expects an *iterable*. Your iterable is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion comes from the fact that you are indeed *slicing* and not *indexing*. Observe:

```
>>> L = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> L[2] = []
>>> L
['a', 'b', [], 'd']
```

Note that `L[2:3]` is "identical" to `L[2]` in regards to the range of 2-3 just being 2 (because slicing is non-inclusive). However, slicing and indexing are two different behaviours, because slicing can change the length of the list, whereas indexing simply modifies an existing element.

---

The reason why the empty list works that way is because of how the slice assignment works. When you're assigning to a slice, python unpacks what you give it and stores its results into the indexes. Observe:

```
>>> L = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> L[2:4] = 'e'
>>> L
['a', 'b', 'e']
>>> L = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> L[2:4] = 'efgh'
>>> L
['a', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

The behaviour of `L[2:4] = 'e'` and `L[2:4] = ['e']` is the same in python because of the behaviour of strings in Python: they may be iterated through and hence unpacked.

So when you put `L[2:4] = []`,  it will unpack all the elements of `[]` and assign their contents into indexes 2 and 3. Of course, since there are no elements, it will assign them to nothing (note: different to `None` or `""` - literally nothing), and hence be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply! I understand this difference. The thing i don't understand is why it was choosen to use empty list as a "delete" in this slicing case.

Answer (score 0):

Slicing does't change the length, assignment does.
Slicing extracts.
Indexing selects a single element. 
Indexing doesn't change the length, assignment does.

```
>>> L = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> L[2:4]   
['c', 'd'] # that's the extraction of a slice.
>>> L[2:4] = []  # that's assignment using a slice and an empty list as operands.  
>>> L
['a', 'b'] 
>>>L[1]
'b'   # that's the selection of an index 
>>>L[1] = 0
>>>L
['a', 0] #that's assignment using an index and integer as operands.
```

So, extracting from a list of strings should still leave you with a list of strings, not strings and empty lists -- that would be a change of type.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign to a slice of a list, the right hand argument must be an iterable object. That iterable is unpacked, and the values replace the values in the sliced part of the original sequence. For slices with step size one (or negative one), this works regardless of whether the slice and the iterable are the same size.

Consider these examples:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a[1:3] = [5, 6, 7]
print(a) # prints [1, 5, 6, 7, 4]

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a[1:3] = [5]
print(a) # prints [1, 5, 4]
```

The specific situation you're asking about is just an edge case of this behavior. When you assign an empty list to a slice, the sliced values are removed and nothing replaces them. Any empty iterable object will work the same way.

This is not the standard way to delete items though. The normal way is using a `del` statement. A slice assignment like `a[1:3] = []` is exactly equivalent to `del a[1:3]`, but the latter is preferred as it's is much more explicit about what it is expected to do.

Comment: You helped me too - i didn't know that it can be any iterable object, not only a list :)